# Problemas com login de usuario

Tags: java, login

Hoje, eu faço minha conexão com banco de dados usando `jpa`. No meu `persistence` eu tenho 2 PU , uma é pra conectar no meu "Gestor" , que é onde está os meus endereços dos banco de dados, e a outra é pra conectar no banco de dados dos clientes.

Até ai eu fiz, o meu problema é o seguinte, quando eu faço uma conexão com um cliente X, ele entra tudo certo , mas ai o cliente Y resolve entrar no sistema, quando eu faco a conexão, o cliente some e passa a ver os dados do cliente Y.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz, de como eu fazer com q o cliente X permaneça logado com seus dados mesmo q o cliente Y entre no sistema

Segue minha persistence :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="GestorPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>Entity.Cadgru</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:C:\BANCOS\GESTOR.FDB"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="SYSDBA"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="masterkey"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
  <persistence-unit name="MitryusPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>Entity.Cadusr</class>
    <class>Entity.Cadloj</class>
    <class>Entity.Cadfun</class>
    <class>Entity.Tipcli</class>
    <class>Entity.Tipven</class>
    <class>Entity.Vendas</class>
    <class>Entity.Venda_Sintetico</class>
    <class>Entity.CodigoPin</class>
    <class>Entity.Codloc</class>
    <class>Entity.VendaEvolucao</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="SYSDBA"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="masterkey"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Segue minha conexao :

```
package DAO;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class Conexao {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf ;

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager(String PU, String Local) {

                if(PU.equals("0")){
                    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("GestorPU");
                }else{
                    Properties props = new Properties();         
                    props.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:" + Local);
                    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PU, props);
                }


        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
        public static EntityManager getEntity() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

}
```

Segue meu DAO :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package DAO;

import Entity.Cadgru;
import Entity.Cadusr;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.Query;

/**
 *
 * @author Felipee
 */
@Stateless
public class GestorDAO {

    Cadusr retorno;
    public static Cadusr usu = new Cadusr();

    public Cadusr buscaPorId(String gr, String usr, String senha) {
        EntityManager em = Conexao.getEntityManager("0", null);
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        Cadgru cadgru = em.find(Cadgru.class, gr);
        tx.commit();
        em.close();
        if (cadgru != null) {
            EntityManager em2 = Conexao.getEntityManager("MitryusPU", cadgru.getEndfdb());
            EntityTransaction tx2 = em2.getTransaction();
            tx2.begin();
            String jpql = "select a from Cadusr a where a.nomusr = :nomusr and a.pasusr = :pasusr";
            Query query = em2.createQuery(jpql, Cadusr.class);
            query.setParameter("nomusr", usr);
            query.setParameter("pasusr", senha);
            try {
                retorno = (Cadusr) query.getSingleResult();
                tx2.commit();
                em2.close();
                if (retorno == null) {
                    em = Conexao.getEntityManager("0", cadgru.getEndfdb());
                    tx = em.getTransaction();
                    tx.begin();
                    tx.commit();
                    em.close();

                }
            } catch (NoResultException nre) {

            }

        } else {
            retorno = null;
        }


        return retorno;
    }

    public String usuarioLogado() {
        String Usuario = usu.getCodusr() + "-" + usu.getNomusr();
        return Usuario;
    }

    private String convertStringToMd5(String valor) {
        MessageDigest mDigest;
        try {
            //Instanciamos o nosso HASH MD5, poderíamos usar outro como
            //SHA, por exemplo, mas optamos por MD5.
            mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

            //Convert a String valor para um array de bytes em MD5
            byte[] valorMD5 = mDigest.digest(valor.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            //Convertemos os bytes para hexadecimal, assim podemos salvar
            //no banco para posterior comparação se senhas
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (byte b : valorMD5) {
                sb.append(Integer.toHexString((b & 0xFF) | 0x100).substring(1, 3));

            }

            return sb.toString();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

esse e meu filter :

```
package Util;

import Entity.Cadusr;
import static com.sun.corba.se.spi.presentation.rmi.StubAdapter.request;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author Felipee
 */
@WebFilter(servletNames = {"Faces Servlet"})
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        String uri = req.getRequestURI();

        if (session.getAttribute("usuarioLogado") != null ||
                uri.equals("/") ||
                uri.equals("/index.xhtml") ||
                uri.contains("javax"))  {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            res.sendRedirect("/MitryusReports/index.xhtml");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Esse e meu SessionContext :

```
package Util;

import Entity.Cadusr;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author Felipee
 */
public class SessionContext {

    private static SessionContext instance;

    public static SessionContext getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SessionContext();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private SessionContext() {

    }

    private ExternalContext currentExternalContext() {
        if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("O FacesContext não pode ser chamado fora de uma requisição HTTP");
        } else {
            return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        }
    }

    public Cadusr getUsuarioLogado() {
        return (Cadusr) getAttribute("usuarioLogado");
    }

    public void setUsuarioLogado(Cadusr usuario) {
        setAttribute("usuarioLogado", usuario);
    }

    public void encerrarSessao() {
        currentExternalContext().invalidateSession();
    }

    public Object getAttribute(String nome) {
        return currentExternalContext().getSessionMap().get(nome);
    }

    public void setAttribute(String nome, Object valor) {
        currentExternalContext().getSessionMap().put(nome, valor);
    }

}
```

pg :

```
<h:head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="description" content=""/>
<meta name="author" content=""/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Vetor Sistemas - Login</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/your_style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/smartadmin-production.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,300,400,700"/>

    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"/>



</h:head>
<body >

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4" id="div_login" >
    <div class="well no-padding">
                <h:form id="login-form" class="smart-form client-form">
        <header>
                            MitryusWeb
        </header>
                    <fieldset>
                        <section>
            <label class="label">Grupo</label>
            <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-group"></i>
                                <input type="text" id="gr" name="grupo"  jsf:value="#{mbeanUsuario.grupo}"/>
            <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right"><i class="fa fa-user txt-color-teal"></i> Entre com o nome do grupo</b></label>
                        </section>
                        <section>
            <label class="label">Usuario</label>
            <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
            <input type="text" name="usuario" jsf:value="#{mbeanUsuario.usuario}"/>
            <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right"><i class="fa fa-user txt-color-teal"></i> Entre com o nome de usuario</b></label>
                        </section>
                        <section>
            <label class="label">Senha</label>
            <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock"></i>
            <input type="password" name="password" jsf:value="#{mbeanUsuario.senha}" />
            <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right"><i class="fa fa-lock txt-color-teal"></i> Entre com sua senha</b> </label>
            <div class="note">
            <a href="forgotpassword.html">Esqueceu a Senha?</a>
            </div>
                        </section>
                        <section>
            <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" checked=""/>
            <i></i>Salvar Credenciais</label>
                        </section>
                        <footer>
                            <h:commandButton type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Entrar" action="#{mbeanUsuario.Vusuario}"/>


                        </footer>



                    </fieldset>
                </h:form>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/masked-input/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $("#gr").mask("****-****");
});
</script>
```

bean :
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Controller;

import DAO.GestorDAO;
import Entity.Cadusr;
import Util.SessionContext;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean

public class mbeanUsuario {

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(mbeanUsuario.class);
private String Usuario;
private String Grupo;
private String senha;

public GestorDAO gestor = new GestorDAO();

public String Vusuario() {
    String retorno;
    Cadusr user = gestor.buscaPorId(getGrupo(), getUsuario(), getSenha());
    if (user != null) {
        logger.info("Tentando logar com usuário " + Usuario);
        SessionContext.getInstance().setAttribute("usuarioLogado", user);
        retorno = "codigo_pin.xhtml";
    } else {
        retorno = null;
    }

    return retorno;

}

/**
 * @return the Usuario
 */
public String getUsuario() {
    return Usuario;
}

/**
 * @param Usuario the Usuario to set
 */
public void setUsuario(String Usuario) {
    this.Usuario = Usuario;
}

/**
 * @return the Grupo
 */
public String getGrupo() {
    return Grupo;
}

/**
 * @param Grupo the Grupo to set
 */
public void setGrupo(String Grupo) {
    this.Grupo = Grupo;
}

/**
 * @return the senha
 */
public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}

/**
 * @param senha the senha to set
 */
public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}

/**
 * @return the gr
 */
```

}

```
insira o código aqui
```

Comment: Onde está a classe que armazena o usuário que está logado na sessão?

Comment: entao , isso q eu preciso fazer, como q eu crio ela , eu vi uns tutoriais com filter aqui mas nao deu certo, vc tem algo pra me indicar ?

Comment: Eu ia lhe indicar justamente o uso de `filter`. Enfim, quais foram as dificuldades encontradas na utilização do `filter`?

Comment: bom vamos la , vou editar ali e colocar oq eu fiz

Comment: entao, o problema aii é q quando eu chamo outra pagina ele abre, e na tela de login ele nao abre o css

Comment: Quando você utiliza essa classe com os filtros, ocorre algum erro no processo de autenticação ou só esse problema com o css?

Comment: Você está logando no sistema usando o mesmo navegador? Se está, o sistema vai usar a mesma sessão.

Comment: ja tentei com maquinas diferentes e da a mesma coisa

Comment: sem erros, e sem css

Comment: Por favor, você pode colocar o código da sua página que está sendo exibida sem o css?

Comment: Coloquei o a pg e o bean

Comment: alguem sabe me ajuda ??